Pulling a table Chart from An App in QlikCloud Using Python
I am trying to pull a table chart from Qlik Cloud and convert to Panda Dataframe in my Jupyter Notebook.
I tried the below code, it was able to connect and read from an App but could not pull the object table with an id "ZgGPbV" to my Jupiter notebook and convert to panda dataframe.
import requests
import pandas as pd      

# Configuration
qlikcloud_url = "https://mytenant.eu.qlikcloud.com"
api_key = "api key"
table_object_id = "ZgGPbV"

# Headers for the API request
headers = {
  "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

# Endpoint to fetch the table data
endpoint = f"{qlikcloud_url}/api/v1/apps/{app_id}/objects/{table_object_id}/data"

# Fetch the table data
response = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
     table_data = response.json()

 # Function to parse the table data into a list of dictionaries
def parse_table_data(table_data):
    rows = table_data['dataPages'][0]['matrix']
    columns = table_data['dataPages'][0]['columns']

    parsed_data = []
    for row in rows:
        parsed_row = {}
        for col, value in zip(columns, row):
            parsed_row[col['name']] = value['qText']
        parsed_data.append(parsed_row)
    
    return parsed_data

# Convert the table data to a list of dictionaries
parsed_data = parse_table_data(table_data)

# Convert the list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(parsed_data)

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)

# Optionally, save the DataFrame to a CSV file
df.to_csv("qlikcloud_table_data.csv", index=False)

else:
print(f"Failed to fetch data. Status code: {response.status_code}")
print("Response text:", response.text)

I was getting Failed to fetch data. Status code: 404
Response text:

There could be something wrong with the url. Here are the solutions you can try - https://community.qlik.com/t5/Official-Support-Articles/How-to-approach-Qlik-Sense-Error-404-Not-Found-The-following-URL/ta-p/1714974

I cant see the /api/v1/apps/{app_id}/objects/{table_object_id}/data in the specification. https://qlik.dev/apis/rest/apps/

Thanks @StefanStoichev.  this api endpoint /api/v1/apps/{app_id} works, I could connect to an app but I added this /objects/{table_object_id}/data to pull the table chart from an app but unfortunately it could not work. Please, what api endpoint can I use to add to /api/v1/apps/{app_id}  for me to read a chart or pull a chart from an app and convert it to dataframe panda in my Jupyter notebook

I might be wrong but i dont think there is a REST API for getting data from a object. All these operations are performed on Engine level and the communication is done via web socket. For JS there is qlik's enigma.js pakcage that helps when "talking" to the Engine but im not aware for python specific. You can start from https://qlik.dev/apis/json-rpc/qix/ to get an idea of the communication principles

There are no REST endpoints today to return data directly from an object in an app. However, you have several potential routes here:

Leverage the QIX (engine) APIs to grab the hypercube data, either from the object or a definition
Leverage the Python Platform SDK to make this easier, it has handlers for interacting with the engine API which make what you're trying to do much easier - note that it is still in preview, Qlik has no published plans on it's future. There are examples of usage against REST APIs in this repo, unfortunately nothing for engine APIs.
Leverage the Reports REST API if your request isn't time sensitive and you need a data file. This will export up to 1M rows of data with sense-data-1.0, but output is limited to XLSX format
Use Qlik Application Automation as the interface to the app. With the Qlik Cloud Services connector you can open an app, make selections, and retrieve table data, which trigger using a REST call to a URL with an execution token. This will remove the need for interactions directly with the engine API.

